# Regular expression match any character at the beginning end with specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

```
"bar foo test-line drop-line"
```

I need to replace the words that starts with anything and ends with '-line'.

basically having:

```
"bar foo new_word new_word"
```

I tried:

```
string.replace(/\.-line$/g,'new_word')
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: hmm.. that doesn't work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as a regex:

```
/\S+-line(?![-\w])/
```

The word anchor is not suitable here since dashes are not considered part of a word, so `/\S+-line\b/` would mistakenly match `text-with-line-not-to-be-replaced`. Hence the lookahead construct.

Of course, according to your use case, `\S` may seem a little coarse. If your words really only consist of letters then dashes etc, then you can use the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern:

```
/[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*-line(?![-\w])/i
```

(normal: `[a-z]`, special: `-`)

(edit: changed the lookahead construct, thanks to @thg435)

Comment: I'd write the lookahead as `(?![-\w])` to take care of possible punctuation.

Comment: fantastic thanks. I only don't understand the last part (?![-\w]) could you please explain it? thanks a lot

Comment: This is a negative lookahead. It means "find a position where what follows is not a dash or a word character". The general construct is `(?!...)`, where `...` is a regex.

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression, you can use \b to detect beginning of new words and \w for "word characters":

```
"your string".replace(/\b\w+-line\b/g,'new_word')
```

See http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: It just depends of what you consider is a word. If you want to include minus characters, just do that: "".replace(/\b[-\w]+-line\b/g,'new_word')

Comment: This is not a question of what _you_ consider a word boundary but what the regex engine considers a word boundary...

Comment: @fge That's correct. \w and \b come along together. Minus is not a word character for browsers, so if you want to consider minus as a word character in your pattern, you cannot use word boundaries. Let me rewrite the regex then: "".replace(/[-\w]+-line(?=(\s|$))/g,"new_word") ... NB: The last part means that a word can be ended either by a white space or by the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
string.replace(/\b\S+-line\b/g,'new_word')
```

`\b` Word boundary

`\S` non whitespace

As fge astutely notes, we need a `\b` after `line` so we don't catch things ending `lines` `liner` etc etc etc

Comment: Will match `foo-bar-lines` and replace it with `foo-new_words`!

Comment: @user1600124 try with the input I mentioned in the comment and see

Comment: @fge Added another word boundary. Many apologies!

Comment: @ElRonnoco the real problem here is that `\b` cannot be used; `-` is not considered part of a word!

Comment: Well the OP wants things that start with "anything" and end with `-line`. I have taken a loose meaning of "anything" here to be 'word' characters - which for both the OP's examples is fine. Admittedly it would fail to match `-something-line`...